# While statement not outputting checkbox in first row of data

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have a while loop that is pulling 3 bits of data from mysql. First name, last name, and email. The unique ID of the row of data is stored in the checkbox as shown at the link below, but the checkbox is not showing up on the first row.

```
//displays the customer rows with checkboxes for deleting
$query= "SELECT * FROM email_list";
$result= mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="' .$row['id'] . '" name="todelete[]" />';
    echo $row['first_name'] ;
    echo ' ' .$row['last_name'];
    echo ' ' .$row['email'];
    echo '<br />';
    }

    mysqli_close($dbc)
```

When the code is run, it shows like this: http://dev123abc45.vacau.com/remove_email.php

So you can see that the first row of data is not getting a checkbox, and I can't figure out why. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in the code you posted, it's in the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/remove_email.php" <-- Look right here
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="todelete[]" />
```

You missed the `>` for your form tag.

Comment: Shoot that was too easy, my bad. Thanks Brendan